# Data aggregation based on date

Tags: database, aggregate-functions, visual-foxpro

I've a table like this (ldate d, amt n(7), rdate d). Fields are loan date, amount, release date.

Here, a record is considered pending which has an empty release date. For example,

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) FROM TABLE WHERE RDATE = {}
```

gives the nett pending amount till date

When calculating pending amount for a given date, a record is considered as pending if it has an empty release date or if it has been released later than the given date! So to calculate pending amount on {2011-10-09}, the query is:

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) FROM TABLE WHERE LDATE <= {2011-10-09} AND (RDATE > {2011-10-09} OR RDATE = {})
```

Now, how would I calculate pending amount year-wise from the above table? The result I expect is like this:

```
Year    PendingAmt 
2009    1,15,000 
2010    1,38,000 
2011    1,71,000
```

Note: The actual table has many other fields. For brevity, I've mentioned only the important fields here. RDBMS used Microsoft Visual Foxpro 9.0

**Update:** added sample data

```
CREATE TABLE VB(LDATE DATE, AMT NUMERIC(7), RDATE DATE);

INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2010-01-05', 12000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2010-03-15', 25000, '2010-04-19');
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2010-05-21', 31000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2010-07-03', 58000, '2010-07-11');
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2010-09-10', 47000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2010-11-30', 63000, '2011-01-09');

INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2011-02-15', 21000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2011-04-05', 52000, '2011-04-11');
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2011-06-03', 13000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2011-08-21', 85000, '2011-09-19');
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2011-10-30', 74000, '2012-02-10');
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2011-12-10', 36000, '2012-03-29');

INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2012-01-05', 15000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2012-02-15', 25000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2012-03-15', 35000, NULL);
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2012-10-30', 30000, '2012-11-21');
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2012-11-30', 31000, '2012-12-31');
INSERT INTO VB VALUES('2012-12-10', 12000, NULL);
```

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT YEAR(loan_date) yr, SUM(rupees) pamt FROM vb WHERE loan_date <= DATE(YEAR(loan_date),12,31) AND (ret_date > DATE(YEAR(loan_date),12,31) OR ret_date = {}) GROUP BY yr`.
 This one provides me some amount grouped by year but the amount is definitely wrong. Could someone help me getting the right result?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Based on the data you've now provided, and the additional information included there (like the fact that rDate isn't empty for the unpaid loans, but is null, here's the improved query:

SELECT YEAR(ldate) yr, SUM(amt) pamt ;
  FROM vb ;
  WHERE (rdate > DATE(YEAR(ldate),12,31) OR ISNULL(rdate)) ;
  GROUP BY yr ;
  INTO CURSOR result

The results I get with this are:

2010 153000
2011 14400
2012 87000

Based on my understanding of your problem, that's correct.

Comment: Sorry, that didnt help. It produces the same result!

Comment: Can you give us CREATE CURSOR and INSERT commands to set up an example that we can use.

Comment: @tamar-e-granor From the sample data (updated the question) SELECT 2010 YR, SUM(AMT) PAMT FROM VB WHERE (LDATE <= DATE '2010-12-31' AND (RDATE > DATE '2010-12-31' OR RDATE IS NULL));
gives 2010, 153000. Likewise for 2011 & 2012 the pamt is 234000 & 211000 respectively. What I wanted is: 

 2010 153000, 2011 234000, 2012 211000 as three rows

Note: I don't know how many years of data is in the table and hence can't use some concrete values for year. The query have got to be a generic one to retrieve the pending amount year-wise! Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is a union:

```
SELECT 2009 as yr, SUM(AMT) as amount
FROM TABLE
WHERE LDATE <= {2009-12-31} AND (RDATE > {2009-12-31} OR RDATE = {})
union all
SELECT 2010 as yr, SUM(AMT) as amount
FROM TABLE
WHERE LDATE <= {2010-12-31} AND (RDATE > {2010-12-31} OR RDATE = {})
union all
SELECT 2011 as yr, SUM(AMT) as amount
FROM TABLE
WHERE LDATE <= {2011-12-31} AND (RDATE > {2011-12-31} OR RDATE = {})
```

Comment: That's fine but what if I don't  know how many years of records are in the table?